# Remote Desktop won't launch

Tags: remote-desktop, osx-mountain-lion, apple-remote-desktop

Remote Desktop is giving an error upon launch:

> The remote Desktop client software on this computer does not match
>   the administrator software version. The Remote Desktop administrator
>   software requires a newer version of the client software. Click "Check
>   for Updates" to search for updated software.

I've reinstalled Remote Desktop from the App Store multiple times and am running the latest version of OSX (10.8.4).
I recently installed the preview of 10.9 but downgraded back to 10.8.4 by doing a migration assistant on a 10.9 time machine backup. This may be the culprit, but I wouldn't know how to fix this problem I'm having.

Additional info:
In System Prefs -> Sharing -> Remote Management says:

```
Remote Management is not installed on this computer.
```

Comment: "downgraded back" : did remote desktop ever work on this computer and for which OS version? What OS version on the target computer?

Comment: Remote Desktop worked when computer was at 10.8. I upgraded to 10.9. I then downgraded to 10.8. Now Remote Desktop is not working.

Comment: Have you fully patched 10.8.4 (Software Update) ? See also if [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2124056?start=0&tstart=0) helps, and especially the answer [by ÜberMacHead](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10332909#10332909) (after adaptation to your osx version).

Comment: I have fully patched OS X. I checked the answer by UberMacHead, it seemed to have brought back my "Remote Management" in Sharing under System Preferences, but Remote Desktop is still giving me the same error upon launch.

Comment: Try to download from Apple and install the Remote Desktop client update.

Comment: ermm, that's what I did. see the answer below.

Comment: Should have posted this as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed 3.6.2: http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1594 manually which isn't available on the App Store (where I usually downloaded it from), and it works now.

Comment: It seems I need to downgrade the client to match the admin version? http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1570

Comment: The installer you linked to is just a 3.6.2 update. You still require the full install of ARD first (non-Mac App Store) to install the update.